# SubSonic 2.2 Not Fully Update For VB?

Tags: subsonic

An answer to a recent question on extending SubSonic pointed to a googlecode directory listing the relevant ActiveRecord templates.  I was very surprised to see that most of the CS_ ones are a lot newer than the VB_ equivalents.  Does this mean that SS2.2 has not been fully updated for VB?

Answer (score 1):

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985834/subsonic-vb-net-problem/993832#993832)

For the reasons why vb.net isn't fully "baked" for 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I committed a patch to the templates and made sure it was included in the VB versions. There weren't many template changes for 2.2, so it should still be fine. Is there something not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I was kind of surprised that the date stamps had changed on most of the CS_ ones, and not the VB_ ones.

In my case, I'm not having much luck with Winforms data binding, although I not a recent item on the GoogleCode buglist which may be applicable.  I think that one is post-2.2?