# Subsonic 2.2 + MySql 5 + StoredProcs = 'SPs' is not a member of 'SubSonic'?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, subsonic

I have been using SS2.1 for quite a while now and have been loving it.  However, I noticed that 2.2 was out so I thought it would be best to upgrade.  After dropping 2.2 into my bin folder, it no longer builds the stored procedures from MySQL that were working so perfectly with v2.1.  What happened?  What am I missing here?

On "Rebuild Application" my error list stacks up with:

'SPs' is not a member of 'SubSonic'

and

Name 'SPs' is not declared.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and raise the ire of Rob Connery and say that SubSonic 2.2 is half-baked. He's working hard on version 3 as well, so some of this stuff is probably oversight.

Unless you have issues preventing you from using 2.1, I say stay at 2.1 for now, until the kinks are worked out.

[See this post for more issues with 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793493/subsonic-2-2-not-fully-update-for-vb/993835#993835)

Answer (score 0):

Well, while this issue definitely was annoying and perplexing to say the least, I actually found Rob VERY willing to work with me on getting it patched.  I am very happy to report that through some judicious code digging, direct communication with Mr. Conery and digestion of previous issues of similar nature, we have patched this SP bug and this was committed to the SVN trunk over a week ago.  I apologize for not repoting back that this issue was resolved.

If you were experiencing this issue, please grab the most recent source from Google Code, compile and go!

Thanks to Rob for his guidance on this one.  I am a happy camper again.  Subsonic rules!